# Unable to set string to object

Tags: java, android, eclipse, mobile, media-player

got my code working. Just having a little trouble with one part.

```
    public void picksound(){

Intent mIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(mIntent, 1);
}


 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent mIntent) {
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != mIntent) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {

            Uri selectedRing = mIntent.getData();

    }
}}

private void playSong(String selectedRing){
    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        mp.setDataSource(selectedRing);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        mp.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mp.start(); 
}


public void alarmmsg(){
    //ringtone player
    playSong(selectedRing);
    //
```

So that's the code I am working with. When I try to call the playSong function, I am asked for a string, and the only string it seems to accept is "null". Can someone help to see what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line :

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
```

To this:

```
MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse("http://www.urltofile.com/file.mp3"));
```

Comment: Didn't seem to do anything :/